# kotlin - automatic conversion of numeric types

Tags: type-conversion, kotlin, implicit-conversion

**In java**, we can assign `int` to `double`, for example `double x = 123`;

**In kotlin**, we got a compiled error.

Question: Can we enable automatic conversion feature in `kotlin`? Why `kotlin` don't have this feature by default?

```
var x: Double = 123; // ERROR
```

One more example:

```
fun foo(x: Double) { }

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
   foo(123.0);  // OK 
   foo(123);    // ERROR
}
```

**UPDATE:**

*the literal `123` can be automatically converted to `Short` or `Long` at compile time. But it will not be converted to `Float` or `Double`.*

```
fun fooShort(x: Short) {}
fun fooInt(x: Int)     {}
fun fooLong(x: Long)   {}


fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    fooShort(123)  // OK
    fooInt(123)    // OK
    fooLong(123)   // OK
}
```

Comment: Kotlin wants to know if you are doing something intentional or accidental.  If it allows implicit conversion, then we would never know and the compiler cannot help.  Implicit conversions have statistically been shown to be a large number of bugs, mystery bugs, evil bugs.  Kotlin does not allow this because it wants the developer to state intent, not guess at it.  There are no plans to change this.

Comment: In Java you do not assign an `int` to a `double` , you instead go through a process of widening followed by an assignment.    You can read the less-than-simple explanation of everything that can happen: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. This isn't going to happen. As `kotlin` is strongly typed meaning *types aren't coerced implicitly*. You need an explicit type conversion. From the Kotlin reference for [Explicit number conversions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/numbers.html#explicit-number-conversions) it is stated:

> Due to different representations, smaller types are not subtypes of bigger ones.
> [...]
> As a consequence, smaller types are NOT implicitly converted to bigger types.
> [...]
> We can use explicit conversions to widen numbers.